# Layout changes when android:id is changed

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

When I change the android:id in xml file items in layout becomes unorganised[image: before]

when android:id is changed in xml file layout becomes like this
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.rms.Suppliers" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Supplier DETAIL" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="NAME" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="20"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="20"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Delete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Modify" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Show" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="ADDRESS" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="CONTACT" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Item" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="View" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="View all" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:text="Add" />
```

i got the reason why this happening because i am using RelativeLayout then using toLeftOf, belowOf but what is the solution i mean is there any code/key word to make it permanemt while i want to use realtive layout only
any help would be appreciated and please don't mind if its childish I am beginner

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Changing id results in changes, as there might be some other layout that is assigned `layout_below` attribute or some other attribute that might result in changes.

Comment: @sajjan This code shows like exact your first image. Which id you changed?

Answer (score 0):

Your `button1` has a `layout_below` attribute that uses id of `textView3`

If you change id of `textView3` to `textView33`, you also have to make change in `button1` like this as the id of `textView3` is referred in `button1`

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView33"  //had to make one change here too
  android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
  android:text="Add" />
```

Comment: i got the reason why this happening, what is the solution i mean is there any code/key word to make it permanemt while i want to use realtive layout only

Comment: There is a solution, but i wont **recommend** that. You can remove `android:layout_below` attributes and use `android:layout_marginTop` to arrange elements.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using relative layout, views used in your layout like TextView, Button, EditText etc... are placed relative to each other. For this relative placing of views in layout, it will use the id `(android:id="@+id)` as reference.

for ex:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="View all" />
```

Button is placed to left of `editText2`.

So don't change the ids once created. If you want to change, again you may need to re arrange the views (like textview, button ....)

Answer (score 0):

In references, don't write '@+id', make the reference with only '@id'.

For example, change:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
```

to:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/editText2"
```

You should only have in mind that your reference must be declared before hand (in this case, editText2 must be declared above button5 in your xml file)